# How to bypass the need for registration in order reply to an invitation?

Tags: linkedin

I recently received an invitation on Linkedin from someone who share my field in IT.

I think I have enough passwords to memorize, and I dislike http based social networks.
However, he send the invitation from his Linkedin account *(so it was sent from a no reply e‑mail address)*.

Is there a way to bypass the need for registration in order to see his full profile *(with using the sharekey in the invitation url)* ?
Or more generally, a way to contact him ?

Comment: Stop memorizing passwords by getting a password manager.

Comment: @mgkrebbs : [which is worst than password reuse](https://www.undernews.fr/authentification-biometrie/opera-sync-pirate-17-millions-identifiants-et-mots-de-passe-en-fuite.html). More generally I don’t like those kind of networks. I already decided to not contact him if creating an account is really required.